# How do you set global custom headers in Angular2?

Tags: http-headers, content-type, angular

I want to set the header `Content-type: application/json` in all my requests to my backend in Angular2. I use this in my main `app.js` file.

```
let headers = new Headers({
    'Content-Type', 'application/json'
})
class MyOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
  headers: headers 
}

bootstrap(App, [
  provide(RequestOptions, {useClass: MyOptions}),
  ROUTER_BINDINGS,
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  bind(APP_BASE_HREF).toValue('/')
])
```

I'm expecting all uses of `Http` to use the new content-type, but this code still has the content-type set to `text/plain`

```
saveMaster (master) {
  return this.http
    .put(`${config.API_URL}/masters/${master._id}`, JSON.stringify(master))
    .map(res => res.json())
}
```

I have to manually set the headers for each request to get it work correctly. Am I doing something wrong?

**Note:** I want to set a header option globally, not have to set it with every request type like is found in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464108/angular2-set-headers-for-every-request).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 - set headers for every request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464108/angular2-set-headers-for-every-request)

Comment: @MarkRajcok That answer is still setting custom headers for every type of request manually. I'll try alexpods solution tomorrow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Change `MyOptions` to:

```ts
class MyOptions extends RequestOptions {
  constructor() { 
    super({ 
      method: RequestMethod.Get,
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Some-Header': 'some-content'
      });
    });
  }
}
```

2. Put `provide(RequestOptions, {useClass: MyOptions})` **AFTER** `HTTP_PROVIDERS` (otherwise default `BaseRequestOptions` will be used instead of  your `MyOptions`).

```ts
bootstrap(App, [
  // ...
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  provide(RequestOptions, {useClass: MyOptions}) // <- after HTTP_PROVIDERS!!!
])
```

See [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Yoi17x9bXIhgnWcC4rEa?p=preview)

Comment: This work nicely. Sadly this does not work with dynamic headers (eg: header that depends on cookies that may change). The constructor will be only evaluated once at loading.

Comment: For dynamic headers, you can extend the http class and modify the `request` method to add custom headers for every request. I've written a comprehensive guide for this - http://www.adonespitogo.com/articles/angular-2-extending-http-provider/

Comment: For **NG4+** (I'm currently on Angular 6) this answer worked for me => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464108/angular-set-headers-for-every-request/45221680#45221680