# server and client are hosted on same url, and yet I get CROS error

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, http, angular, jersey

I have this code:

client (angular2) hosted on this url:

```
http://localhost:8080/Me/html/pages/gasolina/country/USA
```

code:

```
  return this.http
          .post(this.supporToolSaveUrl, gasConfigModel, {headers: headers})
          .map(res => res.json())
          .subscribe(
            data => {
              console.info("next: ");
              console.info(data)
            },
            err => console.error(err)
          );
```

server (java jersey)

hosted on this url:

```
http://localhost:8080/Me/services/SaveConfig
```

code:

```
 @Path("/SaveConfig")
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
    public void saveConfig(CountryGasStationConfig countryGasStationConfig) throws Exception {
```

should  i add these in jersy annotation?

When i run locally i get this error:

```
MLHttpRequest cannot load http://locahost:8080/.... Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)
```

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111936/angularjs-performs-an-options-http-request-for-a-cross-origin-resource/20516179#20516179) and this post

How can i make this solution in angular2?

app.

```
config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
  //Reset headers to avoid OPTIONS request (aka preflight)
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {};
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = {};
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {};
}]);
```

Comment: It's unclear whether you're using angular2 or angularjs. Your http request at the top is angular2 while the config you're posting is angularjs. They're different frameworks and can't work together. Could you clarify?

Comment: @FedericoP read the question again...it's quite clear

Comment: Try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464108/angular2-set-headers-for-every-request/34465070#34465070