# angular 2 final - Add global header for Http

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-services

I'm using Angular 2 final version and I search a lot about my question but I did not find something that works for angular 2 final.
How to add a global header and withCredentials = true for every Http requests at Angular 2 final?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 - set headers for every request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464108/angular2-set-headers-for-every-request)

Comment: @jcamelis that is not for angular 2 final, the things changed since from RC5

Answer (score 0):

I could figured out how to this. Just add a new provider at you main module (app.module.ts)

```
{
provide: Http,
useFactory: (backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: BaseRequestOptions) => {
  defaultOptions.withCredentials = true;
  defaultOptions.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
  defaultOptions.headers.append('Accept', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
  return new Http(backend, defaultOptions)},
    deps[XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
```

}