# Laravel 5.2 passport authentication with angular 2

Tags: laravel, authentication, angular, laravel-5.3

I'm just new to laravel passport so it is kind of confusing to me. I have watched [Taylor otwell](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/13) tut on passport but still I am not able to figure out that **Is it possible to authenticate an angular app with laravel passport**?

What I want to do is build a `Full SPA` application with `angular 2` as `frontend` and `laravel 5.3` as back-end. I've used `JWT` for authentication with laravel on `version 4.2` but just want to know if it is do able through laravel passport.

Your `comments` and `answers` will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible but it's also more complicated then it was in Angular 1.

This entry could be helpful:

[Angular2 - set headers for every request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464108/angular2-set-headers-for-every-request)

because you need to pass CSRF token to the app to consume your application as it's written here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript

Comment: How do you get the CSRF token to the client if your application is decoupled from the API?