# Angular2 and backend Authentication

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular2.

My backend server has "Spring Security" implemented.
User needs to send **username & Password** for LDAP Authentication .

In reference to : 
[Angular2 - set headers for every request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464108/angular2-set-headers-for-every-request)

This is how i am trying :

```
login(username:string,password:string) {
     let headers = new Headers();
     this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers,username,password);
    return this.http.get(this.url,headers).map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError).subscribe(e=>console.log(e));
  }

private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || { };
  }

createAuthorizationHeader(headers:Headers,username:string,password:string) {
   headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
   headers.append("x-requested-with", 'XMLHttpRequest'); 
  }
```

but i get 401 , but my credentials are correct. When i try them using Rest client it works perfectly fine.

[image]

I checked on server logs, request is reaching there but unfortunately not much information from there.

When i debug on frontend side, i see valid value in Authorization header (encrypted) before request being fired.

**UPDATE**

Productive code (Angular1):

In Angular1 it is implemented like this :

```
function logIn(username, password, callback) {
            var token = "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password);
            authenticate(token, callback);
        }                                                                                                              function authenticate(token, callback) {
            if(token.indexOf('Basic') > -1) {
                var headers = {
                Authorization: token,
                    "x-requested-with": 'XMLHttpRequest'
                };
                var url = ConfigService.getConfig("backend").url;
                return this.$http({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: url + "login",
                    withCredentials: true,
                    headers: headers
                }).then(function (success) {
                    $log.debug("AuthService.successfully logged in.");
                    var user = success.data;
                    user.auth = headers.Authorization;
                    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = user.auth;
                    setUserInfo(
                        user,
                        new Date().getDate() + expireTime);
                    callback(success);
                }, function (error) {
                    if(error.status === -1) {
                        ToastService.showError('There seems to be a CORS problem. Do you use the right server?', error);
                    } else {
                        ToastService.showError(error.statusText, error);
                        $log.error('credentials must be wrong.');
                    }
                    $log.error(error);
                });
            }
        }
```

I dont see any difference between my implementation and production code.
Please help with this.

Thanks

Comment: Your header code looks good to me. Can you check api if it's receiving or processing the header correctly?

Comment: @SefaÜmitOray : yes it is implemented correctly, matter of the fact is it is working with Angular1(in production)