# ng2 - injecting a provider into a regular class

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I can typically inject any provider into my components, but is this limited to components? Is there any way to inject `ActivatedRoute` into a regular class which is used in this context:

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    AuthenticatedRequestOptions,
    { provide: RequestOptions, useClass: AuthenticatedRequestOptions }
  ],
  ...
})
```

authenticated-request-options.model.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticatedRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
    constructor(@Inject(ActivatedRoute) public route: ActivatedRoute) {
        super();
        console.log('route', this.route);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it as parameter to your constructor

```
constructor(route: ActivatedRoute, private injector: Injector) {}
```

`AuthenticatedRequestOptions` needs to be provided somewhere `@Component()`, `@NgModule()`, ... and the class needs to have the `@Injectable()` decorator

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticatedRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
```

and the class needs to be injected itself.
If you create an instance with `new AuthenticatedRequestOptions(...)` Angulars DI is not involved and you need to pass parameters yourself.

Comment: As I mentioned, this didn't work either. injector is undefined in my example

Comment: I extended my answer.

Comment: I updated my question with new code that follows these suggestions and still injects nothing.

Comment: You don't need `@Inject(ActivatedRoute)` if the type is the same `route:ActivatedRoute`. It's just redundant. Otherwise I can't tell from the code you provided. The root cause has to be somewhere else. The code in the question is fine now. Can you reproduce in a Plunker? Plunker provides a ready-to-use Angular2TS template with the "New" button.

Comment: That's so greate about Plunker. Just creating one solves losts of issues ;-)

Comment: Indeed, I realized the issue while making it. You're right, the issue was elsewhere. I needed to extend `RequestOptions` not `BaseRequestionOptions`. Commented on this here, where I got the original code:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/39866166/1267778

Answer (score 1):

`@Inject` allows to inject dependencies into providers even if they don't have `@Injectable` decorator, the proper syntax is:

```
export class AuthenticatedRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
   constructor(@Inject(ActivatedRoute) private route: ActivatedRoute) {
   ...
```

In order for a provider class to make use of type annotation for DI it should have `@Injectable` decorator:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticatedRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
   constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
   ...
```

Comment: I updated my question with new code that follows these suggestions and still injects nothing.