# How can I send a JWT token to an external URL?

Tags: angular, jwt, redirect

I have two REST end points.

1. `accounts.mydomain.com/login` - An identity provider, sends a JWT token as response once a user is authenticated with his username/password.
2. `api.mydomain.com/users` - Accepts the above JWT token as `Authorization` header, verifies it and sends user JSON as response if the token is valid.

I have created my UI using Angular2

1. A login page at `myservice.mydomain.com`, which captures username/password and `POST`s the credentials to the rest endpoint 
   `accounts.mydomain.com/login` and gets JWT token as response. Below page will be shown once the JWT token is received.
2. A home page of users at `users.mydomain.com`. This page should be shown only if the above JWT token is verified against the rest endpoint `api.mydomain.com/users`.

I though I would send the JWT token from the response of login page to `users.mydomain.com?t=JWTtoken` using `window.location.href` and get the token from query param to send it to `api.mydomain.com/users` as `Authorization` header.

I know that, if the JWT token size is increasing, sending the token in the query parameters is not good.

Can anyone suggest me a better way to achieve the above requirement? Is it possible to send the JWT token in the header instead of query parameter?

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible to send JWT token as a header. In `Angular2` you have a collection of headers on the request API that you can augment. You don't have an interception in `Angular2` it seems, but you can always just write your own wrapper on top of the HTTP client to store the token and append it to every request in a header.

This is in fact the most common way of passing a JWT token or any other token to the API (you can send it in cookies as well, e.g. but I prefer header for various reason like maintainability and security).

This is how you set a header:

```
import {Headers} from 'angular2/http';
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append(headerName, value);

// HTTP POST using these headers
this.http.post(url, data, {
  headers: headers
})
```

You can read more about wrapper in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464108/angular2-set-headers-for-every-request).