# How to apply a jwt token to generated Angular 2 JS files?

Tags: javascript, angular, authorization, token, generated

Angular2 Typescript application is generating source .js files.

While debugging I observed that the authorization header is undefined.

I have `jwt` token for custom services defined.

How can I apply the same `jwt` token to generated Angular2 source .js files?

Comment: check this out for setting up token in http header http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464108/angular2-set-headers-for-every-request

Comment: Your question is not very clear, there's no code ... You're gonna have to give us more than a bounty to help you ;)

Comment: Hi Guys, my question is around - the security of code(ts/js) files- if any browser asks for the generated code(ts/js), this security should be applied, may be redicted to login, if no jwt token present.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is not related to generated js files. The easiest, fastest and most comfortable solution is to use npm module `angular2-jwt`.

- Install the module`npm install angular2-jwt`.
- Configure your app.module.ts like this:

  ```
  import { AUTH_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2-jwt';
  @NgModule({
    ...

    providers: [
      AUTH_PROVIDERS
    ],

    ...
  })
  ```
- Then use it everywhere you want in your app by:

  ```
  import { AuthHttp } from 'angular2-jwt';
  this.authHttp.get('http://example.com/api/thing')
    .subscribe(
      data => this.thing = data,
      err => console.log(err),
      () => console.log('Request Complete')
    );
  ```

That way your requests would be authenticated if you have your token in a cookie named `id_token`. If you want to store your token by another method (localStorage, indexedDb...) please, refer to the module's documentation (https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt#configuration-options) on how to change it, but it is fairly easy. If you need it I can explain it right here.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from your short post, you just want to send the token in http request header. I use the same strategy on my applications and I don't use any extra module.

I have an authentication request and I store my token on localStorage:

```
this.http.post('/login', userCredentials).subscribe(
    token => localStorage.addItem('Authorization', token),
    error => this.handleError(error)
)
```

Then I just get the token from localStorage and use it in my requests headers:

```
let options = { headers: new Headers() };   
let jwt = localStorage.getItem('Authorization');
options.headers.append('Authorization', jwt); 

return this.http.get('/api/request', options)
           .map(result => result.json());
```

In my opinion, angular2-jwt is useful if you want to decode your jwt.