# How to set header for HTTP in Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

So basically I need to add custom auth header to all requests referred to API. In constructor I want to add this header and then in the class methods just use `this.http`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Config, Events } from 'ionic-angular';

import { Http } from '@angular/http';


@Injectable()

export class APIRequest {

    constructor (
        private http: Http,
        private config: Config,
    ) { 
        this.http.headers.append('My-Custom-Header','MyCustomHeaderValue');
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 - set headers for every request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464108/angular2-set-headers-for-every-request)

Comment: @SabbirRahman no, i dont want to set header in each method. I need to set it once in constructor.

Comment: You can create anther service and wrap HTTP there. So there are post, get, .... with your custom header.

Answer (score 2):

I use common fuction this way for headers

```
let method = 'POST';

let requestOptions: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({
headers: this.jsonHeaders(),
method: method
});
```

`jsonHeaders()` // Function

```
public jsonHeaders(): Headers {
let headers: Headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
headers.append("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
headers.append("Cache-Control", "no-store");
headers.append("If-Modified-Since", "Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");

if(this.token) {
headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.token);
}

return headers;
}
```

`HTTP Request`

```
let url = '/login'
this.http.request(url, requestOptions)
```