# catch error from http observable when use custom http wrap

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I create custom http service like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464108/angular2-set-headers-for-every-request) to add header in every request.

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpClient {
  constructor(public http: Http) {
  }

  prepareH(hde: Headers){
    hde.append("Authorization","Bearer "+XXXXX)
  }

  get(url) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.prepareH(headers);
    return this.http.get(url, {
      headers: headers
    })
  }
}
```

then in main page, i make http request like this

```
this.httpclient.get('http://someurl/xxxx').subscribe(
    res=>{
        console.log(res)
    },
    err=>{
        console.log(err)
    }
)
```

it work fine i can get response in res block but http error 4xx or 500 never go to err block. I don't know why? How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

forget it, error also go to error block. Just my typo,sorry