# how to set a header for http get using angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

How can I add a header for username and password for GET Request in http in angular2?

I am try to add httpclient and http import is not working. Can you suggest to me how to add a header in http and pass my username and password?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 - set headers for every request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464108/angular2-set-headers-for-every-request)

Comment: My question is how to pass the username and password to the headers

Comment: You know is not securable to implement this?

Comment: It is simple json file for my training purpose

Comment: If it is only for testing, you could just create something like this:

`http.get('http://{yourserverurl}?username=' + username + '&password' + password).subscribe(() -> {
 // This here is the response.
});`

Answer (score 0):

> You can set the header like this:

```
yourMethodWhereYouPost(userName:string, password:string) 
{
    // ....
    // Your code 
    //

    // Get the authorization header.
    const authHeader = this.getAuthorizationHeader(userName, password);
    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    headers.append('Authorization', authHeader);
    // ....

    // Some more code
} 

private getAuthorizationHeader(userName: string, password: string): string 
{
    // Return the encoded auth header.
    return btoa(userName + ':' + password);
}
```