# Angular Rest Api header call issue

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I want to set header for all request. don't want to set header for each request again and again like i have code like this

```
public update(student: Student): Promise<Student>
{
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('authentication', `${student.token}`);

    const url = `${this.studentsUrl}`;

    return this.http
        .put(url, JSON.stringify(student), { headers: headers })
        .toPromise()
        .then(() => student)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

so is there any way from which i can set generic header for each request ?

Comment: did you tried to search http interceptors ? which angular version you are using

Comment: @Rahul angular 4

Comment: angular 4.3.0 onwards HTTP interceptors are supported. So If you are using angular 4.3.0+ then interceptor is best possible option. See my answer below

Comment: below angular 4.3.0 inceptors are not there?

Comment: can you give any example of regarding how can we set generic header for each http request in angular 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** :

To add generic header below angular 4.3 you may need to develop custom service.
Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34465070/1608841) answer which explains best possible solution prior to angular 4.3.

Hi you can try HTTP interceptor:

> **Note** : HTTP interceptors are supported by Angular 4.3+

This is interceptor file

```
import { Injectable, NgModule} from ‘@angular/core’;
import { Observable } from ‘rxjs/Observable’;
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest} from ‘@angular/common/http’;
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from ‘@angular/common/http’;
@Injectable()
export class MyInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
      const dupReq = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set(‘Consumer-Secret’, ‘some sample key’) });
      return next.handle(dupReq);
   }
};
```

and in app.module.ts :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MyInterceptor } from './interceptors/my.interceptor';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: MyInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Please refer to [this](https://alligator.io/angular/httpclient-interceptors/) site for reference

Comment: can you map your code in my example which i mentioned in question?

Comment: when you add this interceptor file in your project; interceptor will always intercept each and every http request and process whatever you write in interceptor