# ionic native http get return typeError - Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

Few minutes ago I created a new project in the newest Ionic. I imported

```
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http'
```

and after that I tried to send GET request to my backend application.

```
meetingsUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/test/all';
 this.http.useBasicAuth('login','password');
    this.http.get(this.meetingsUrl,{}, {'Content-Type':'application/json'})
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

I'm using 'ionic cordova run browser' command. I tried run on android, but it was the same effect.

In every case I got error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
    at getMatchingHostHeaders (advanced-http.js:118)
    at getMergedHeaders (advanced-http.js:126)
    at Object.get (advanced-http.js:210)
    at callCordovaPlugin (plugin.js:110)
    at plugin.js:136
    at util.js:22
    at new t (polyfills.js:3)
    at tryNativePromise (util.js:21)
    at getPromise (util.js:29)
    at wrapPromise (plugin.js:119)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have done it wrong. You need to set the `headers` details.

See the [**doc**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/#get)

```
get(url, parameters, headers)
```

Example [**from the doc**](https://github.com/silkimen/cordova-plugin-advanced-http#get):

```
    this.http.get('https://google.com/', {
      id: 12,
      message: 'test'
    }, { Authorization: 'OAuth2: token' }).then(data => {
       console.log(data.status);
       console.log(data.data); // data received by server
       console.log(data.headers);
  })
  .catch(error => {
      console.log(error.status);
      console.log(error.error); // error message as string
      console.log(error.headers);
  });
```

Comment: I have header: Content-Type':'application/json. But I want to use basic auth with login and password, not oauth2

Comment: That was just an example of the doc.See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34465070/1077309

Answer (score 2):

Example for LogIn request, where `AppSignIn` is the URL like http://www.example.com/

```
public signInRequest(login:Login):Promise<OAuth> {
        let params:URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
        params.set('userId', login.userId.toString());
        params.set('password', login.password.toString());
        let requestOption:RequestOptionsArgs = {
            search: params
        };
        return this.http
            .get(AppSignIn, requestOption)
            .toPromise()
            .then(this.extractData)
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
doLogin(){

   let base64Auth = this.http.getBasicAuthHeader("username", "password"); // return like {Authorization: "Basic base64UsernameAndPassword" } 

   this.http.get("url", {}, base64Auth).then((res)=>{
      //success callback 
      console.log(res); 
   }).catch((err)=>{
      //error callback 
      console.log(err); 
   }); 

}
```