# Angular 4 JWT token shows "401 unauthorized"

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, authorization, asp.net-authorization

I've seen similar threads to this issue, but I had no luck solving it.

I'm trying to access my .net core controller "GET" using angular post.

```
getAll() {
    return this.http.get('api/Users/GetAll', this.jwt()).map((response: Response) => response.json());
}
```

I'm getting this error :

> 401 Unauthorized

jwt code :

```
private jwt() {
    // create authorization header with jwt token
    let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser') || '{}');
    if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + currentUser.token)
        return new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    }
}
```

`currentUser.token` consist a valid token, I can access it via console.log, etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/postman). See if your code has issues or request is actually unauthorised. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34465070/3331861)

Comment: postman also says the same - Unauthorized

Comment: I don't know any about JWT toke, but in https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/04/06/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/ Jeffrey T. Fritz  write 'bearer' (in lowecase). Sorry if it's a stupid observation

Comment: Check your logs of the .NET Core application. I assume you use the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` library. This should log (if you setup [logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x) correctly (for example `AddDebug()` for VS Output logging). There you should be able to see why JWT is invalid according to your 'back-end'.