# How to implement user's info inside JWT token in spring-boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Good moorning everyone !

I'm working on a project with spring boot (JWT & Spring security ) and Angular5 in front-End .

I'm now in a phase where i need to send the authenticated user's ID with the JWT token so i can use it front-End in many operations ..

**First Question** :

I'm not using Auth2 , only JWT , How can i implement this ? I can not find any complet exemple with JWT .

**Second Question** :

I saw some exemples where they use class UserTokenEnhancer that implements TokenEnhancer , it's used in a class that extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter  while my config class is extending the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  .

Are there any similar way on how to do the same with JWT ?

Searching for these information for along time but with no result , Hope i get any answer here .

Thank you in advance :) .

**Edit**

**This is** JWTAuthenticationFilter.java

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    
             private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
            @Autowired
            private UserRepo userRepo;
    
            @Autowired
             private AccountService accountService;
    
             @Autowired
              public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
              this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
           }
    
            @Override
            @Autowired
            public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
                super.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
            }
    
        @Override
        public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
    
            AppUser appUser = null;
            try {
                appUser=new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(),AppUser.class);
            } catch (IOException e) {
               throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
            }
    
             return authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(appUser.getUsername(),appUser.getPassword()));
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
    
            User springUser = (User)authResult.getPrincipal();
            String jwt = Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject(springUser.getUsername())
                    .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+SecurityConstants.EXPIRATION_TIME))
                    .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256,SecurityConstants.SECRET)
                    .claim("roles",springUser.getAuthorities())
                    .compact();
    
            System.out.println("****"+jwt);
    
              AppUser app = userRepo.findByUsername(springUser.getUsername());
              Long id = app.getId();
    
              ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
              JsonNode jsonJwt = objectMapper.readTree(jwt);
              ((ObjectNode)jsonJwt).put("userId", id);
    
    
           
               response.addHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING,SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX+objectMapper.writeValueAsString(jsonJwt));
    
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

Erros i'm fascing concerns JsonParseException at line **JsonNode jsonJwt = objectMapper.readTree(jwt);**

Here is the error :

```
 com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImV4cCI6MTUyNzU5NjA2Mywicm9sZXMiOlt7ImF1dGhvcml0eSI6IkFETUlOIn1dfQ.gkoGLsdVxgJURhfGQkn5pbs6KyO6ikCAILQeR4j0ikk; line: 1, column: 21]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1702) ~[jackson-core-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:558) ~[jackson-core-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2839) ~[jackson-core-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddValue(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1903) ~[jackson-core-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:749) ~[jackson-core-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3850) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3799) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:2397) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at interv.Web.security.JWTAuthenticationFilter.successfulAuthentication(JWTAuthenticationFilter.java:81) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at interv.Web.service.JWTAutorizationFilter.doFilterInternal(JWTAutorizationFilter.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
```

Class JWTAuthorizationFilter.java

```
 package interv.Web.service;

import interv.Web.security.SecurityConstants;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;

public class JWTAutorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{


    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {


        httpServletResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
        httpServletResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", " Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization");
        httpServletResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials,Authorization");
        httpServletResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET,PUT,POST,DELETE");


        String jwtToken = httpServletRequest.getHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING);

         if(httpServletRequest.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")){
             httpServletResponse.setStatus(httpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        }
         else {
             if(jwtToken==null || !jwtToken.startsWith(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX)){

                filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest,httpServletResponse);

                 return ;
             }

             Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                    .setSigningKey(SecurityConstants.SECRET)
                    .parseClaimsJws(jwtToken.replace(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX,""))
                    .getBody();

            String username = claims.getSubject();
            ArrayList<Map<String,String>> roles = (ArrayList<Map<String,String>>)claims.get("roles");


            Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
            roles.forEach(r->{
                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(r.get("authority")));
             });

            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken=
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username,null,authorities);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
            filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest,httpServletResponse);
         }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Can'nt you simply send UserId and othe info in Response body and JWT token in a header.?

Comment: Can you please take a look of what i tried to do  , i've updated the post , what do you think about it ? becaus i'm still fascing errors with it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if the following is the absolute best "Spring way" to do this, but you should be following these rough steps:

First, you will need to authenticate your user against your data store (e.g. using `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` and a `DaoAuthenticationProvider`) and build a `User` object. At the end of successful authentication you should have a valid `User` object in your `SecurityContext`.

After that, create and sign the token. I highly recommend using JWE (there are libraries that support this). Remember, a *signed* token only verifies that it was not tampered with: unless the subject is encrypted *in addition to being signed*, anyone can read the token. "Create" the token means that you should serialize your `User` and put it into the `subject` of the token payload.

Then, assumming that your clients will supply the token back to you using some header (i.e. `x-my-token`), you will need to register a `Filter` that snags the incoming `HttpServletRequest` and checks for the presence of this header. Optionally depending on your requirements, you check the expiration of the token (that you set when creating it).

Still in the filter, after decoding the payload and decrypting your subject (hopefully!), you deserialize the subject into a `User` object that you place in the `SecurityContext`. If the token is expired (if you checked that), or if you cannot deserialize a valid `User` (perhaps the user was deactivated in the meantime, something you might check with a DB CHECK / user store cache, or the subject in the token is somehow malformed), you would throw an exception. On success, you continue the filter chain as normal.

Once this is done you will have a valid `User` that you can retrieve (i.e. using `SecurityContext.getPrincipal()`) and use in your application to perform authorization (i.e. using `@PreAuthorize(hasRole(...))`, `@PreAuthorize(hasPermission(...))`, etc.).

If you wish to only allow authenticated users access to your infrastructure, that's all you will need to do.

If you would like to allow anonymous access, there are two ways that I know of:

1. Do not throw an exception upon failing to find an authentication header, and simply continue the filter chain. This results in there not being a valid `User` in the `SecurityContext`, and any attempt to access a protected resource will result in an exception.
2. Add an additional `Filter` component that runs after your normal authentication filter, i.e. `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter`. In it, you would populate a stub `User` if none was found. This user should have `ROLE_ANONYMOUS` and no otherwise valid ID values that might conflict with other users of your system (i.e. `id = -1`).

You might also take a look at the filter chain hierarchy and precedence, as there are lots of problems that you might run into if your authentication filters run at the wrong time, i.e. too early or too late.

---

> ' How can i send the authenticated user's id from back end to front end which is angular . Any idea ? im using only jwt not auth2 .

As I mentioned, all your client needs to send is the token that was returned upon authentication.

So, the normal workflow would look like:

1. Client performs `POST /login` with the supplied user credentials, and receives a `JWT`. Client stores this token.
2. Client sends the token as an additional header on every request. I'm not well-versed in Angular, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464108/angular-set-headers-for-every-request) seems to be one way to do it.
3. After that, the process starting with the Authentication `Filter` described above takes over.

Note that the client should have some additional handling to be able to gracefully handle token expiration (if you check it). One way to do it is: add the *plaintext* expiration date and time to the token payload, and check it in the client prior to sending the request. If expired, prompt user to log in again.

---

The last error you have probably hinges on the following lines where you *create* the token:

```
        String jwt = Jwts.builder()
        .setSubject(springUser.getUsername())     <---
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+SecurityConstants.EXPIRATION_TIME))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256,SecurityConstants.SECRET)
                .claim("roles",springUser.getAuthorities())
                .compact();

        System.out.println("****"+jwt);

          AppUser app = userRepo.findByUsername(springUser.getUsername());
          Long id = app.getId();

          ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();     <---
          JsonNode jsonJwt = objectMapper.readTree(jwt);      <---
          ((ObjectNode)jsonJwt).put("userId", id);            <---
```

`String jwt` already contains the encoded JWT string, which means that `objectMapper.readTree(jwt)` attempts to parse `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9...` (i.e. the actual token), which will fail. After creation, the token is essentially *immutable*.

In addition, when creating the token you only say `.setSubject(springUser.getUsername())`. If you wish additional fields to be inside the subject, then you will need to serialize (using `setSubject()`) the additional fields here.

One way to do that is to simply create a class that will hold your user information, i.e. `MyTokenUser, which you will fill with all required fields (i.e.`username`,`userId`, etc.). So:

```
        User springUser = (User)authResult.getPrincipal();

        AppUser app = userRepo.findByUsername(springUser.getUsername());
        Long id = app.getId();

        MyTokenUser tokenUser = new MyTokenUser(springUser.getUsername(), id);

        String jwt = Jwts.builder()
        .setSubject(tokenUser)
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+SecurityConstants.EXPIRATION_TIME))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256,SecurityConstants.SECRET)
                .claim("roles",springUser.getAuthorities())
                .compact();

        response.addHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING,SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX+jwt);
```

Alternatively, you might just serialize your `AppUser`, as it seems to have all the required fields already.

Comment: Thank's for answering ! i did the right filters as you said , despite the AnonymousAuthenticationFilter , that's a good idea i will add it next , But my issue now is ' How can i send the authenticated user's id from back end to front end which is angular . Any idea ? im using only jwt not auth2 .

Comment: Updated the answer. Please take a look. Does that answer your question?

Comment: These was very helpful information , can you take a look please to the post i've updated to see what i've tried to do so i can send the  user's id to front end , just to make sur that's the right way .. , becaus i'm still fascing errors with it .

Comment: What kind of errors are you facing? In addition, `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` is meant to be used as a filter for `POST /login` (see: [javadocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.html#attemptAuthentication-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-)) (basically as an alternative to the first paragraph in my answer), not as a general purpose Authentication Filter that populates the SecurityContext based on a given header.

Comment: Ah i see , in fact i was trying to understand a tutorial where they implement JWT this way , I have edited the post again with the error i get .

Comment: Having in mind that your parsing should be in a different filter, you are not actually *parsing* the token. You must use the `Jwts.parser().parseClaimsJwt()` method to parse the token, as it is encoded and signed. After decoding the payload and (if encrypted) decrypting, you will have a string that can be deserialized to a `SecurityUser`.

Comment: back again , Can you please edit your post on how exactly to do this ? it seems like i'm not able to use it correctly

Comment: Edited the answer. This should solve your issue. Please have another look at JWTs and their use, as you seem to have some misconceptions about them.

Answer (score 1):

Looks Right to me, Just do something like this,, forward the Request to a Controller and return the Body.

```
@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException { 
  //Write token in the Response as response.addHeader();
  tokenAuthenticationService.addAuthentication();
  chain.doFilter(request, response); 
}
```

you added the response Header, after that just forward that to the Controller like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
     public Output login(
             HttpServletRequest request,@RequestBody UserDto 
      userDto) throws UserServiceException {

         logger.info("Entering login ");
         return Obj;
}
```

Then you can return whatever Output you want in the response in addition to JWT Token Header.

Comment: I'm sorry but should i add this line chain.doFilter(request, response);  at the beggining of the method ? another question where to put the second one public Output login ?

Comment: @Override
 protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
   FilterChain chain, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException { // Do all Stuff . chain.doFilter(request, response); } . After that request will be Forwarded to the Controller /login