# Angular 6 HTTP Get request with HTTP-Basic authentication

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, rest

I`m trying to access a URL with *Basic Authentication*.

The URL returns JSON data.

How can I add my username and password to this http request below?

```
private postsURL = "https://jsonExample/posts";

getPosts(): Observable<AObjects []>{
    return this.http.get<AObjects[]>(this.postsURL); 
}
```

Comment: Can you use `post` method instead of `get` ? If you are using `get` then you should append credentials to the header of a request

Comment: Have a look over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34465070/4736140

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Refer to https://angular.io/guide/http or https://v6.angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('username:password')
  })
};
```

Then use the headers:

```
return this.http.get<AObjects[]>(this.postsURL, httpOptions);
```

Comment: thanks a lot .

I try this and i get this as response 

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'wwww.xxxxxx.de/re' from origin 'http://localhost:9000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Comment: @YupYup Please ask a new question for a new problem. Basic Auth and CORS are two very different things.

Comment: I added httpOptions as your advice. But now I have a new problem. The problem is get request transformed to Options request and server does not support Options Method. How can I send request as Get not Options?

Comment: @kira are you using `http.get()` ? Do you use any header that relates to a different method, like pre-flight request?

Comment: Yes I am using http.get().I wrote a question [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58779934/angular-8-httpclient-get-method-transforms-to-options-method)

Comment: Hello, btoa(username:password) there is a problem with some characters, like üçşğöÖŞĞ? How  can I solve this.

Answer (score 17):

i don't know what you want to do exactly after getting authorized, but to get authorized using a simple call with basic authentication you need to do like this:

```
let authorizationData = 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password);

const headerOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        'Authorization': authorizationData
    })
};

this.http
    .get('{{url}}', { headers: headerOptions })
    .subscribe(
        data => { // json data
            console.log('Success: ', data);
        },
        error => {
            console.log('Error: ', error);
        });
```

Comment: for {headers: headerOptions} . I am getting issue : cant be assigned as RequestOptions

Comment: be aware that this fails for non-ascii characters: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64#the_unicode_problem

Answer (score 0):

Since `btoa()` ist deprecated the following might be a cleaner solution than https://stackoverflow.com/a/53613780

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const username = 'JohnDoe'
const password = 'JonhnsSecret'

const token = Buffer.from(`${username}:${password}`, 'utf8').toString('base64');

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token)
  })
};
```

Then use the headers:

```
return this.http.get<AObjects[]>(this.postsURL, httpOptions);
```